# XMLPullparser getEventType returns 0 always

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

```
XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
pullParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(new StringReader(xmlResponse.replace("&","&amp;")));
int eventType = parser.getEventType();
```

In the event type i always get 0 only and looping in while.  my Xml Response is

```
  <ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode>
  <ResponseMessage>Success</ResponseMessage>
  <CategoryCount>10</CategoryCount>
  <CategoryMaster>
    <CategoryId>001</CategoryId>
    <CategoryFullName>BreakFast</CategoryFullName>
    <CategoryShortName>Break</CategoryShortName>
    <SubCategoryMaster>
      <SubCategoryId>007</SubCategoryId>
      <SubCategoryFullName>Idiyappam</SubCategoryFullName>
      <SubCategoryShortName>idi</SubCategoryShortName>
      <price>25.00</price>
    </SubCategoryMaster>
  </CategoryMaster>
```

please advice me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way.

```
  XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    pullParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

parser.setInput(new StringReader(xmlResponse.replace("&","&amp;")));
int eventType = parser.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag "+parser.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag "+parser.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text "+parser.getText());
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot to add  parser.next();

Comment: @SathyaSri glad to help you.